# Add values of int array to values of another int array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two int arrays of the same length 5, array1 & array2. I want to add the values of array2 to the values of array1. Is there a faster/more concise way to do this other than a simple for loop? Maybe using LINQ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array1[i] += array2[i];
```

Comment: You can even LINQ this, but the legibility will be a lot worse.

Comment: Two lines of code... Can't be that bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ, you can use [Enumerable.Zip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
array1 = array1.Zip(array2, (a, b) => a + b).ToArray();
```

I doubt that it's faster though, and "more concise" is also questionable. For one thing, it has to allocate a whole new array instead of updating in-place like your `for` loop does.

Comment: Thank you, yes after timing this vs the for loop, the for loop is consistently faster.